# Loops in assembly, having trouble copying an element from specific address in bx to dx and displaying it using ah

Tags: assembly, x86

Hie i am trying to learn the assembly language emu8086. and am currently trying to learn loops. All the questions i will post are because of personal curiosity. at first i input the number of values i will like to enter. The problem is i am trying to use the loop output to display the values i have stored inside bx using the input loop. For some reason my output loop is not working. Please help.

```
                                                                                                      include 'emu8086.inc'
      .model small          
      .code
      start:
      mov ah,01h                                             
      int 21h
      sub al,'0'
      mov cl, al
      mov ch,0
      mov bx,0
      push cx
      input:
            mov ah,01h
            int 21h
            mov [2000+bx],al
            inc bx   
           loop input 

           pop cx
           output:    
            mov dx,[2000+bx]   


            mov ah,02h 

            int 21h  

            inc bx


 loop output
```

end start

Comment: Added an x86 tag. There's more than one processor architecture in the world, and they have different assembly languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

- You need to reset `bx` to zero before the output loop.
- You should end your program by exiting gracefully to DOS using `int 21h` with [`ax = 4c00h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm).